# How to add friends via XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I'm working on an IM application using XMPPFramework. When I want to add a friend, I send a presence stanza, and the friend would be automatically added to XMPPRoster before&whether the other side accepts or rejects. I don't know why. Does any one know? Thanks in advance.
The stanza is like this:
`<presence to='juliet@example.com' type='subscribe'/>`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code and other material. I found that the roster here does not exactly mean what it is in Wechat (a Chinese IM app) or MSN. So those who in your roster does not need to be your friends but the ones who you want to subscribe.